# Samsung Group Play android library

Tags: android, sockets, samsung-mobile-sdk

Am developing an music player, currently seeking for any group play API.. looks like Samsung is providing Samsung Group play SDK i have some questions regarding library.

1. Can i use this library in any device (non-Samsung devices)
2. Can i use this library without any limitations or will Samsung subject later in future to claim my application.
3. Is this library easy to use or there are any better libraries out there.
4. Or is it better to write from sratch